# Dividing colspan in html table

Tags: html, xhtml, html-table

Actually I am new to designing. I have a html table which has three rows description is below

1. Row 1 -- 2 Columns
2. Row 2 -- 1 Column
3. Row 3 -- 3 Columns

Now I want to divide the third row columns in equal partition but unable to adjust the colspan can some one help me here is the code

```
<table width="100%" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" border="1">

    <tr>
        <td align="left">Infodeep Technologies</td>
        <td align="right">3 Minutes ago</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td colspan="3" align="justify">Samsung pioneered the trend of
            a new breed of devices, now more commonly known as
            'phablets',smartphones that are (almost) nearing tablets in size.
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td align="left">By panel.</td>
        <td align="center">21.12%</td>
        <td align="right">21 / 30</td>
    </tr>

</table>
```

Comment: Is this really tabular data that you are trying to display? If not then you shouldn't be using tables for layout purposes - you should just use DIVs etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this is what you want.

```
<table width="100%" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" border="1" >

    <tr>
        <td align="left" width = "50%">Infodeep Technologies</td>
        <td align="right" colspan = "2">3 Minutes ago</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td colspan="3" align="justify">Samsung pioneered the trend of
             a new breed of devices, now more commonly known as
             'phablets',smartphones that are (almost) nearing tablets in size.
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>

        <table border = "1" width = "100%" >

          <tr>
            <td  align="left" width = "33%"  >By panel.</td>          
            <td  align="centre"  width = "33%" >21.12%</td>
            <td align="right"  width = "33%" >21 / 30</td>
          </tr>

        </table>

    </tr>

</table>
```

Comment: But I want to divide the third row columns in equal width

Comment: Now the first row columns are not divided into equal lengths.

Comment: Now again the arrangment of third row get disturbed. Just See it

Comment: @NikhilAgrawal what is issue with 3rd row. I cant see anything wrong?

Comment: @NikhilAgrawal oh sorry yes. just wait

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24960/discussion-between-ashreva-and-nikhil-agrawal)

Comment: @NikhilAgrawal Have also updated answer and provided you link to fiddle as well in my above comment

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a `fixed` table layout, this should override the browsers default re-sizing of cells.

```
<table width="100%" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" border="1" style="table-layout:fixed">

    <tr>
        <td align="left" width = "50%">Infodeep Technologies</td>
        <td align="right" colspan = "2">3 Minutes ago</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td colspan="3" align="justify">Samsung pioneered the trend of
            a new breed of devices, now more commonly known as
            'phablets',smartphones that are (almost) nearing tablets in size.
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td align="left" col>By panel.</td>
        <td align="center">21.12%</td>
        <td align="right">21 / 30</td>
    </tr>

</table>
```